# verbatim text inside italic block

Tags: verbatim, italic

I am trying the following:

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]{OCP en Exceptions}
``If you throw a checked exception from a method in your code and the
\verb!catch! is three levels above, \textit{you must declare that
  exception in the signature of each method between you and
  the \verb!catch!}''
\end{frame}
```

Somehow I can't use the verbatim text inside the italic block. How do I solve this the right way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use verbatim material inside another macros argument. The already mentioned [`cprotect`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cprotect) package works around that, but I would call it overkill using it here. Simply use a font *declaration* inside a group instead of a font macro, i.e. `{\itshape text \verb+$%^+ text}` instead of `\textit{text \verb+$%^+ text}`.

Applied to your code example:

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]{OCP en Exceptions}
``If you throw a checked exception from a method in your code and the
\verb!catch! is three levels above, {\itshape you must declare that
  exception in the signature of each method between you and
  the \verb!catch!}''
\end{frame}
```

Also using verbatim only to get the font effect is a misuse. Simply use `tt` font directly! For often used real verbatim material I would recommend to define them as macros using `\verbdef` of the [`verbdef`](http://ctan.org/pkg/verbdef) package. (There is also `\Verbdef` of my [`newverbs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/newverbs) package if you need it in an expandable form, but normally this is not the case.)

Answer (score 6):

Use `cprotect` package. More details, see the manual.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cprotect}
\begin{document}
\cprotect\textit{\verb|\LaTeX| is one of my primary weapons}
\end{document}
```